# Laravel 7 composer autoload error caused by PHP UOPZ extension

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have my Laravel 7 app uploaded on VPS server running on the subdomain. Everything is fine, index.php opens for the subdomain, I have generated an app key and installed composer packages.
Then I got 500 internal error. Here is a screenshot
[image]

The error has something to do with composer autoload.

Here is the list of things I tried doing.

`php artisan cache:clear`
`composer update`
Deleting vendor folder and running `composer install`

Comment: you can remove composer.lock and try again

Comment: Since you found the culprit it might be worth rephrasing this question to indicate a composer error while using UOPZ (since the VPS part here is not the actual issue). Also please share your error message instead of the screenshot as it will make it easier for people who google this problem to get to this question

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found the solution.
I had tried all sorts of things like deleting `composer.lock` or `vendor` and running `composer update/install` and it did not help.

Finally disabling `PHP UOPZ` extension solved the problem.

For Ubuntu 16.04
`phpdismod oupz`
`systemctl reload apache2`

Comment: please update your PHP to 8